# Javascript : Pulling date from array of objects and comparing it

Tags: javascript, arrays, date, object, comparison

Lets say I have a array with users like this

```
const users = [
  {
    id: 1,
    first_name: 'Urbain',
    last_name: 'Pluvier',
    gender: 'Male',
    avatar:
      'https://robohash.org/voluptasaccusantiumfugit.png?size=50x50&set=set1',
    dob: '1996-01-18 02:44:17',
  }
```

How can i pull out 'dob' (date of birth) from it if i want to compare it to the other date to find out if that person is an adult.

Comment: `new Date(users[0].dob)`??

Comment: `users` is an array, so to access the first element you use `users[0]`. That in turn is an object, so to access its `dob` property, you append `.dob`.

Answer (score 0):

users[i].dob // where i is the index of the array's element

of you can get an array of dobs only with .map if that helps you in any way i dunno

users.map(it => it.dob)